# How to delete a particular word in paragraph using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a paragraph which contains several instances of the word "manish". I want to remove those lines which contain the word "manish", without altering the remaining lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cheapest and easies way would be to simply do:

```
$text = str_replace('yourword','',$text);
```

If you have more words, you could pass a array in the first argument (http://www.php.net/str_replace).

Comment: through this code, only that particular word is remove not whole line. i want to remove whole line.

Comment: Define how your lines are seperated.

Answer (score 4):

```
str_replace ('manish', '', $string);
```

Where `$string` is your paragraph.